# Problems with iterating through fileset

Tags: java, ant, ant-contrib

I try to iterate over a directory of wsdl's. For the first I would be happy just to get an output of each file.

```
<target name="messages">
    <foreach target="wsdlList" param="wsdlfile">
        <path>
            <fileset dir="${base.wsdl.src}">
                <include name="*.wsdl" />
            </fileset>
        </path>
    </foreach>
</target>

<target name="wsdlList">
    <echo message="${wsdlfile}" />
</target>
```

The output I get is wsdlList:
     **[echo] ${wsdlfile}** instead of all wsdl files I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `<foreach>`, use the newer `<for>` task. You need to point to `antlib.xml` and not `antcontrib.properties` in `<taskdef>`:

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
    <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${ivy.dir}/antcontrib">
            <include name="ant-contrib*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

Now, you can do this:

```
<target name="messages">
    <for param="wsdl.file">
        <fileset dir="${base.wsdl.src}">
            <include name="*.wsdl" />
        </fileset>
        <sequential>
            <echo message="@{wsdl.file}" />  <!-- Note "@" and not "$" -->
        </sequential>
    </for>
</target>
```

Note that this is `@{wsdl.file}` and not `${wsdl.file}`. That's a parameter that can have a different value each time.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the "messages" target, as a dependency, so that the wsdlfile property is set:

```
<target name="wsdlList" depends="messages">
    <echo message="${wsdlfile}" />
</target>
```